# Memory problem with areg

Tags: stata, fixed-effects-model

*(Not sure if this is on-topic here?)*

I'm trying to regress a model with group-time fixed effects, and many dummies.

```
egen id_t = concat(id year), format(%15.0f)
areg y u2j* j2j* d1* d2* x1 x2, absorb(id_t) vce(r)
```

`d1` and `d2` are  dummies, for each there is hundreds of possible values. `u2j*` is the interaction of one variable, `u2j`, with time dummies:

```
forvalues t=1980/2000 {
    gen y_`t' = (year==`t')
    gen u2jXy`t' = y_`t'*u2j
    (...)
```

I'm running into a memory error ("*You tried to address 81xxxxm, but your system administrator has set max memory to 80g*"). trying to do this. All my dummies have size int, and all other variables are as small as they can be. What else can I try to resolve the memory issue?

#### Statistical Problem

I'll try to simplify/abstract as much as possible. I have matches between firms and workers. Workers can be matched to firms, or not be matched to any firm at all. Both firms and workers have individual characteristics. Also, there can be firm-year specific effects.

I want to compute wages for workers who *join* a firm, hence are new to it. I want to get at the differential effect for those who come from a different firm (`j2j`), and those who come from not being a matched at all (`u2j`). These differential effects are allowed to vary by year.

A wage between worker `i` and firm `j` in year $t$ is hence given by

$$ y_{i,j,t} = \alpha_{j,t} + \beta_1 X_{i,j} + \beta_2 D_{i,j} + \beta_{3,t} \mathbf{1}_{u2j_i, year=t} + \beta_{4,t} \mathbf{1}_{j2j_i, year=t} + \epsilon_{i,j,t} $$

where $D$ is an additional set of (firm / worker specific) dummies, $X$ are firm/worker specific attributes.

Comment: As a purely software question this would be on-topic on [SO] once you edit it to provide a reproducible example and, most importantly, cite the "memory error" specifically. However, I think the most effective solutions are not going to be software related. They will have to involve reconsideration of this model, because the basic problem is that you are trying to estimate tens of thousands of coefficients, which borders on the ridiculous. Would you consider editing the post to explain your *statistical* problem?

Comment: @whuber is the additional information sufficient?

Comment: "Memory problem" is vague, to say the least. Does Stata crash? Does it say "out of memory"? Does it say "matsize too small"? At any rate, I agree with whuber that this is a software question appropriate for SO, although you might be better off asking your question at statalist.org -- if you please cross-link the two forums so that people wouldn't have to answer the same question twice.

Comment: Already cross-posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989240/memory-issue-with-areg Please don't cross-post on SE sites.